# How to change multiple key values in a state hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, state

I have a user object `const [user, setUser] = useState({name: "James", age: 33})`, how can I set the name to `Joe` and age to `25`?

Comment: Do you want to do this after click event or something else?

Comment: Yes, I want. @decpk

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `setUser` and pass the updated state as. But It will replace every time to `Joe` and `25`

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-shadow-d42fo?file=/src/App.js)

```
setUser({
      name: "Joe",
      age: 25
});
```

**If you want to take data from the user and then change the name and the age**

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sammet-u55ig?file=/src/App.js)

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "James", age: 33 });
  const [newUserName, setNewUserName] = useState("");
  const [newUserAge, setNewUserAge] = useState(user.age);

  const changeName = () => {
    setUser({
      name: "Joe",
      age: 25
    });
  };

  function changeUserName(e) {
    setNewUserName(e.target.value);
  }

  function changeUserAge(e) {
    setNewUserAge(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>{user.name}</div>

      <div>{user.age}</div>

      <input
        type="text"
        value={newUserName}
        onChange={changeUserName}
        placeholder="new user name"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={newUserAge}
        onChange={changeUserAge}
        placeholder="new user age"
      />
      <button onClick={changeName}> change </button>
    </>
  );
```